# LOCAL server not installing wordpress

Tags: localhost, admin

Hi all i did the install but now is asking me if i have :    * Are you sure you have the correct username and password? YES
    * Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname? YES
    * Are you sure that the database server is running? NOT SURE

how do i know my local server is running when using /phpmyadmin

i will apprciate any help

sincerely

JIm

Comment: @JIM are you running your local server on Linux ? Mac ? Windows ? Which tool are you using ? EasyPHP ? Wamp ? A custom LAMP stack ?

Comment: Windos   Im using wamp server  abd reads:  This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is down.  when the php has the info that should be calling.. i will appreciate your help

Comment: Have you created a MySQL database and MySQL user for that database, and entered that information into the `wp-config.php` file? (additionally have you renamed the `wp-config-sample.php` to `wp-config.php` ?)..

Comment: Your question isn't clear... what is the situation on the local server, and what is the concern with regards to moving to a production server? I assume you've adjusted the permalinks settings in the dashboard, and have allowed it to write to .htaccess by setting its CHMOD to 777 (temporarily)?

Comment: Follow these steps: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You don't rename the links with .htaccess when using Wordpress. Simply go to `Settings->Permalinks` from your dashboard and select the scheme you want. Going by your sample URL, you could put `/%postname%/` in the Custom Structure field to get just the post name.

Comment: HI JohnP i have tried but still does not change  i have inserted:  /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%.htm   and does not recognizes the page on my local host  only http://localhost/wordpress/?p=123

Comment: Try selecting month and name from the options without entering anything in the custom field. Also, please not that your permalinks **will not** change. Only your pretty links. When you move the blog, you need to change the baseurl. This is set in your wp-config.php

Comment: does'nt work  this template has a default for the =idpage?  and everytime i update the permalinks it overwrites the .htaccess

Comment: The permalinks overriding .htaccess is the expected behavior. If the template doesn't use the proper markup, you might have to change it. Normally, moving the blog only requires that you update the base url. I've done it before and it works without a hitch

Comment: the reason i ask , because 1. i'm working on my local host  2.when uploading the files from my local host to overwrite the new template on my website, what's the procedure?

Comment: The theme can simply be copied to the live server if you've used wordpress' recommended way of linking to blog posts. The data can either be exported and uploaded or you can simply dump the data on your live server and change the base url values.